# Are there any "scp -p" just like "cp -p"

Tags: scp

So if I need to preserve the permissions/user/group infos of files then I can copy them with "cp -p foo fooo". But are there any "preserving" options in scp? When copying between servers.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I suspect the downvotes are because this information is easily found by using `man`, which should be the first source of information when wanting to know more about a utility.

I would encourage people not to downvote a question for that reason. See the discussion here: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203/rejecting-obvious-questions

Comment: ty, but where can you see this in the "man"? -->> "preserve the permissions/user/group" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience I can say that `scp -p`does NOT work as expected.

I use `rsync -e ssh -aHS SOURCE TARGET` instead, This will retain almost all attributes - only the creation time of soft links will change to the current time.

Comment: Really?  It generally works just fine for me.  How exactly does not not work for you, and on what system(s)?

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry for the late answer to your comment. I have this problem (soft-link-time) on CentOS 5.8 and SLES10 SP4. I found no system call that is able to change the time of a soft-link (on these systems) - perhaps that is the source of the problem.